# printing global variable in local block

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x=15;
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    {
        int x = 5;
        cout<<::x; // should print 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to print x=10 without changing variable names, variable values and position of cout?

Comment: 1 possible reason is that `::` will look for the global variable. In this case `x=15` is global variable, and `x=10` is local variable, so it prints `x=15`.

Comment: **Please avoid writing such code.** You need to make your C++ code easily readable, even next year. Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: I know this is not the correct way to code in c++. I posted this question just to know if there is any possibility to print x=10 in correct way. I'm surely not going to write code like this in any of my projects. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is an academic question (puzzle) because nobody should write code like that. In the same spirit, here's a way to make it print `10` instead of `15` without changing variable names, variable values and the position of `cout`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x=15;
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    {
        int x = 5;
#define x x-5
        cout<<::x; // should print 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Normally you should parenthesize such expressions in macros, like `(x-5)`. In this case, that would be counterproductive :)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't

> An inner block, because it is a different block, can re-utilize a name existing in an outer scope to refer to a different entity; in this case, the name will refer to a different entity only within the inner block, hiding the entity it names outside.

Further information here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access x=10 in the inner block where you defined x=5. It can only see x=5 as x=10 is hidden at that point.

```
Ref: 3.3.7/1

A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class (10.2).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind some horrible undefined behaviour, we could make assumptions about where local variables are stored on the stack. This works on my machine™ using g++ without any additional flags (although even `-O1` breaks it):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x=15;
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    {
        int x = 5;
        cout<<*((&x) + 1); // should print 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is based on the assumption that local variables are placed on the call stack (or some other place) consecutively in main memory, in reverse order of declaration. It breaks in many cases, such as having a different order, having `x=10` be placed in a register, or `x=10` being optimized away entirely because it's unused.

Comment: Your answer is working in my Compiler but how it is accessing x=10 by adding 1 to address of x=5 and dereferencing it. Please explain and thank you for the answer.

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 15;
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    {
        int x = 5;
        
    }
    cout << x; // should print 10;
    return 0;
}
```

you should probably put cout<< to outside

Comment: Question specified "without changing position of cout".